# Applying multiple conditions in re.sub()

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am working on a string where I want to remove some special characters. Also I want to remove single characters and numeric values from it but not alphanumeric values. Currently I have to use `re.sub()` multiple times to perform that operation. Can I use multiple conditions in a single `re.sub()`?

```
sample = "[ This - is a 26 sample s string with ? special . characters' s26]"
sample = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9._ "]'," ",sample)
sample = re.sub(r'\b[0-9 .]+\b',"",sample)
sample = re.sub(r'\b[a b c d e f g ..... z]+\b',"",sample)
```

Expected output:

```
sample = "This is sample string with special characters s26"
```

Comment: I don't think so, because the replacements are not the same.  The first call to `re.sub` replaces the pattern with a single space, while the second call removes content.  What is your aversion to making two calls?

Comment: What do you think `[a b c d e f g . . . . z]` means?  Are you aware this the same as saying `[abcdefg...z ]`?

Comment: This condition is for single characters, I have not applied it. I suppose there must be something like 'a-z' for this one also.

Comment: If you only replace with a space or empty string, you may use a callback or a lambda expression as the second argument where you may specify the logic you need.

Comment: As pointed out by @Wiktor your regexes have some problems.  You should get that working first before worrying about other things.

Comment: Yeah, the actual solution will depend on what you exactly want to do. A regular advice is: do not "cram" all conditions into one regex unless there is some justification for it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  :Can you please post a sample code for that.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/HzmmZA

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  :The sample code you provided is working fine. Thanks...

Comment: However, you asked for something very different, and it is a known issue. If you want your question reopened, please modify it to dwell on the original problem and not on conditional replacements.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @WiktorStribiżew. That was the sample code I posted. Now, I will apply it on my real problem. If I face some issues. i will post the whole code along with exact issues... Thanks once again. :)